# The point P lies onOV and is such that PNM is a right angle. Find the position vector of P

Tags: vectors

I dont understand how to find PN as I don't get where P lies I know that the vector $PNxMP=0 $ as it is perpendicular. The shade is a pyramid and And M and N are the midpoints of AB and BV respectively. vector $OA=6i $ $OC=3j$ and  $ OV=9k$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

As Position vector of $A$ is $(6, 0, 0)$, of $V$ is $(0, 0, 9)$ and of $C$ is $(0, 3, 0)$, position vector of
$B$ $(6, 3, 0)$, $M$ $(6, \frac{3}{2}, 0), N(3, \frac{3}{2}, \frac{9}{2})$.

As point $P$ lies on $OV$, we assume its position vector as $P \ (0, 0, z)$. Using position vectors now find direction vectors $\vec {NM}$ and $\vec {NP}$. As they are perpendicular, equate their dot product to zero and find value of $z$.

Comment: but it also gives these values vector $OA=6i $ $OC=3j$ and  $ OV=9k$

Comment: I just edited with values.

Comment: thank you very much but I am very confused on how you got point N

Comment: N is midpoint of B and V so add those position vectors and divide by $2$.

Comment: owww i see i will tyr to do it.

Comment: I hope you were able to finish it. Let me know if you need any further help on this.